# autologin falla

Tags: wordpress

buscaba una solución para loguearse de manera inmediata despues de el registro de un usuario en wordpress, alguien me recomendo un plugin de accessally, pero es muy caro.

buscando por la web me encontré con esta opción, pero no logro hacer que se loguee el usuario

```
$login_data = array();
    $login_data['user_login'] = $user;
    $login_data['user_password'] = $password;
    $login_data['remember'] = $remember;

    $user_verify = wp_signon($login_data, true);

    if (is_wp_error($user_verify)) {
        $errors[] = 'Invalid username or password. Please try again!';
    } else {
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_verify->ID);
        wp_redirect(admin_url());
        exit;
    }
```

algo debe faltarme o sobrarme. No logro hacer que funcione.

Comment: Si estás utilizando WordPress podés aplicar este plugin para poder realizar el autologin, si te fijas también, tenés la opción de escoger a donde se redigirá [Auto Login New User After Registration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-login-new-user-after-registration/)

Comment: GENIAL!!, justo lo que buscaba, al inicio pensé no funcionaría pero era por que no coloque la página a la que redirigiria, Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: que bueno que te funcionó, saludos!

Comment: justo lo estoy revisando y tengo un pequeño inconveniente, hice un formulario personalizado y despúes de registrar el usuario, agrega un campo de ciudad con autocomplete de jquery, y este campo no lo almacena. pero sino ocupo el plugin, funciona bien.
me interesaría saber mas al respecto de wp_signon, gracias.

Comment: Buscá algunos plugins dentro del repositorio de wordpress relacionados al autologin y fijate si lo solucionas, sino tambien edita el codigo del plugin